# How to make select-all only select the "current" region of text via css

Tags: html, css

If you go to `about:gpu` in chrome, the click the mouse somewhere and pick Select-All or press Ctrl-A/Cmd-A, you'll see only a single area is selected.

[image]

Above I'm pressing Cmd-A and expected **all text** to be selected but only the current area is selected.

What CSS makes this happen and can you provide a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to repo the behavior?

I tried setting a parent's style to `user-select: none;` and the children to `user-select: text` which is the only thing that seemed to stick out about that page's CSS but select-all still selected all the text in my example. Further, removing `user-select: none` from the parent element in the `about:gpu` page did not make it start selecting all the text. Further, you can disable JavaScript on that page via the DevTools and it still only selects individual portions of the text (making it clear it's just CSS and or HTML settings that are causing this behavior)

Comment: what part of this question is off topic?